# Symfony trustedproxies doesn't work

Tags: symfony, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, symfony3.x, symfony-3.4

Symfony does not trust my nginx reverse proxy : I can't see the real IP of the user in my logs, everything is logged with IP 127.0.0.1

My config in app.php :

```
Request::setTrustedProxies(
    ['127.0.0.1', $request->getClientIp(), $request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')],
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL
);
```

My nginx reverse proxy config :

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8042;
    proxy_set_header        Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
}
```

Here is a var_dump of the symfony request :

```
  ["server"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag)#9 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
      ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]=>
      string(14) "176.158.246.32"
      ["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]=>
      string(14) "176.158.246.32"
      ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
      string(4) "8042"
      ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
      string(9) "127.0.0.1"
      ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
      string(5) "49538"
      ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
      string(9) "127.0.0.1"
      ["DOCUMENT_URI"]=>
      string(8) "/app.php"
      ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
      string(14) "/debug-request"
      ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
      string(8) "/app.php"
      ["PHP_SELF"]=>
      string(8) "/app.php"
    }
  }
  ["headers"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag)#10 (2) {
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(13) {
      ["x-forwarded-for"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(14) "176.158.246.32"
      }
      ["x-real-ip"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(14) "176.158.246.32"
      }
    }
  }
  ["isHostValid":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["isClientIpsValid":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["isForwardedValid":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request":private]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

Comment: Is nginx directly facing client or behind some load balancer?

Comment: directly facing client

Comment: Did you place the Request::setTrustedProxies after creating the request?

Comment: Could you show us request headers inside Symfony Request? with var_dump() or debugger? Just to be sure that "X-Forwarded.." headers are present and contain client IP.

Comment: @MaksymMoskvychev I've just put the var_dump in the question

Comment: @Airoude I put the setTrustedProxies after the call to Request::createFromGlobals, as specified in the documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#request-set-trusted-proxies
And it seems that symfony's request checks trustedproxies on each call to getClientIp() method.

Comment: @Nanocom, what version of Symfony is it? 3.3 or 3.2 or something before?

Comment: @Nanocom, what do you mean with "everything is logged with IP 127.0.0.1"? Which log file? show some sample record form it, please.